# Dealing with Maybe Bool values

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

Let us say, I have two `Maybe Bool` value and I want to achieve the following functionality:

- If both are `Just` values, I want to perform an `||` between them the values.
- If one of them is `Nothing` and the other one is `Just` value, then I want the `Just` value as the output.
- If both of them is `Nothing`, then I want `Just False` as the output.

I know that this can be achieved using pattern matching. But is it possible to use any monadic functions to acheive the result ?

`liftM2` works for this case:

```
ghci> liftM2 (||) (Just True) (Just False)
Just True
```

But `liftM2` will produce `Nothing` when any of the one input is `Nothing` (for which I want the other `Just` value). i.e:

```
ghci> liftM2 (||) (Nothing) (Just False)
Nothing
```

But I want `Just False` in the above case.

Is it possible to do this using any monadic function ?

Comment: You could `fmap` all `Nothing`s to `Just False` before `liftM2 (||)`

Comment: @Ingo Didn't think that! Can you post the comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Ingo: `fmap _ Nothing = Nothing`

Comment: @TikhonJelvis True. I meant "map" in a general sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The monad instance has no notion of emptiness<sup>1</sup>, so it can't check on `Nothing` and replace the value in that case.

What you basically need is the *monoid* instance; that has `Nothing` as its identity element so whatever you combine with `Nothing` will just come out *as is*.

```
instance (Monoid a) => Monoid (Maybe a)
```

Unfortunately, `Bool` is in itself not a monoid. Well, actually it is a monoid! but not in a unique way, so they couldn't've chosen any particular instances. But with `newtype` wrappers, those are in `Data.Monoid`:

```
newtype Any = Any { getAny :: Bool }
instance Monoid Any
```

let's try it...

> Prelude Data.Monoid> fmap getAny $ (Just $ Any True) <‌> (Just $ Any False)
>   Just True
>   Prelude Data.Monoid> fmap getAny $ (Nothing) <‌> (Just $ Any False)
>   Just False

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, there's `fail`... but that's a historic accident.

Comment: What is `<>` operator ? (Hoogle says me that it is something related to `Doc` )

Comment: @Sibi: It's the [infix version of `mappend`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-).

Answer (score 9):

As it stands, we don't even need to invoke the monadic apparatus. According to your specification, "Nothing" can be mapped to "False" and "Just b" to "b":

```
mbor a b = Just (flat a || flat b)
   where flat = maybe False id
```

As @leftaroundabout correctly points out this essentially is what the Monoid Any instance does.

Answer (score 6):

A very useful operator here is `<|>` from the `Alternative` class in `Control.Applicative`. For `Maybe`, it works like this:

```
Just a  <|> _       = Just a
Nothing <|> Just a  = Just a
Nothing <|> Nothing = Nothing
```

We can also take advantage of the fact that `x || x == x` is always true. This lets us write the following:

```
orMaybe a b = liftA2 (||) (a <|> b) (b <|> a) <|> Just False
```

If both `a` and `b` are `Just x`, the `liftA2 (||)` results in `Just (a || b)`. If one of them is `Nothing`, the `(a <|> b)` and `(b <|> a)` turn into either both `a` or both `b`, resulting in `Just (a || a)` or `Just (b || b)`. Finally, if both are `Nothing`, we get `liftA2 (||) Nothing Nothing` which leads to `Nothing`. The final `<|> Just False` then turns the whole expression into `Just False`.

Now, I think this is a fun exercise to work through. But would I actually use this code? **No**! For `Maybe`, `Nothing` usually signifies failure and propagates; since you're using some very non-standard behavior, it's better to be explicit and pattern-match all the cases instead.

Note: `liftA2` comes from `Control.Applicative`. It's just like `liftM` but for applicatives; I used it for consistency with `<|>`. You could have used `fmap` as well.

Comment: +1. you beat me to it. I'd make it shorter like so: `(||) <$> (a <|> (Just False)) <*> (b <|> (Just False))`

Comment: Is there ever a reason to use `liftM`? Isn't that an accident stemming from the fact that monads weren't always applicatives previously?

Comment: @kqr: basically, yes. Note that monad is currently not a subclass of applicative, so liftM usage is still justified, but after GHC 7.10 monad will likely be a subclass of applicative.